# Как работает Bluetooth BLE в режиме ожидания?

Tags: bluetooth

Нужны ссылки на конктретные места в спецификации объясняющие работу Bluetooth Low Energy в режиме ожидания (после pairing'а, когда не принимается и не отсылается никакой информации).

Находится ли BLE модуль во сне, в данном режиме и если да, то как происходит процесс выхода из сна?